# Swift 3 downcasting JSON Dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3

I'm am currently doing an ios swift app with google maps autocomplete function. In swift 2.0 I did like this to get longitude and latitude value:

```
let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary  
let lat = dic["results"]?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lat")?.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
let lon = dic["results"]?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lng")?.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
```

But with swift 3, it's not working anymore. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, **do not** use `NSDictionary`, use Swift native `Dictionary`
- Second of all **do not** use `valueForKey`, use key subscription
- Third of all **do not** use `mutableContainers` in Swift, use a `var` `Dictionary` if you want to change something.

For convenience declare a type alias of a JSON dictionary

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

In Swift 3 the compiler needs to know the types of **all** intermediate objects, the safest solution is

```
if let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!, options: []) as? JSONDictionary {
  if let results = dic["results"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let geometry = results["geometry"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let location = geometry["location"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let latitudes = location["lat"] as? [Double], !latitudes.isEmpty,
    let longitudes = location["lng"] as? [Double], !longitudes.isEmpty {
      let lat = latitudes[0]
      let lng = longitudes[0]
  }
}
```

For that kind of nested JSON consider to use a library like SwiftyJSON.